# Zachor from a non-kosher Sefer torah

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

We know that one is not yotzeh if he hears Zachor read from a non-kosher Sefer Torah. What is the process of kashering the Sefer Torah so it will be usable? Must one do hag'alah? Does hag'alah work, or do we compare it with earthenware? Furthermore, if it was only used in in a cold setting, is hadacha enough?

(As always, please CYLOR if this is applicable to you in any way.)

---

**This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).**

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69551

Answer (score 16):

The words of Torah are compared to glass, because they're easily lost like glass vessels, and because a Torah scholar who sinned can still do teshuvah, like glass that can be resmelted (Chagigah 15a).

Glass can (in some cases) be kashered using מילוי ועירוי - filling and pouring. A non-kosher sefer Torah, then, can be kashered in the same way: the sofer fills his pen with ink and pours it out onto the parchment in the proper places.

Answer (score 8):

A *sefer Tora* that is not kosher should be put in an earthenware vessel ([*M'gila* 26:2](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=1464&size=1)). However, [*Rava*](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=1068&size=1) said any Torah scholar whose inside is not like his outside is no Torah scholar at all, and a fortiori a *sefer Tora* is no *sefer Tora* unless its inside is like its outside, namely like the earthenware it is in. Thus, a non-kosher *sefer Tora* is like an earthenware vessel.

However, [*Raban Gamliel*](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=53&size=1), who said only that a Torah scholar whose outside is not like his inside cannot enter the *bes midrash*, would hold that a non-kosher *sefer Tora* merely cannot be used in *shul*, but could be used in, e.g., a *shiv'a* house, *lo alenu*. As is evident from [the *g'mara* there](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=53&size=1), we do not hold like *Raban Gamliel* in this regard.

Comment: It seems to me that the proper resolution between these two opinions is to wrap a kosher *sefer Torah* and the nonkosher *sefer Torah* together, with the ends offset by one-half wrap.  In this way, the outside and inside become indeterminate.  The *Glatt* approach would then be to place the whole in an earthenware Klein bottle.