# PTIJ: Why does G-d give us honey cake?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Before returning the Torah to the ark, we say a verse from Mishlei 4:2.

כִּ֤י לֶ֣קַח ט֭וֹב נָתַ֣תִּי לָכֶ֑ם...

For I have given you a good [lekach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lekach).
(Lekach is essentially, honey cake, commonly eaten by Ashkenazim on Rosh Hashannah.)

Why did G-d give us lekach? Why do we mention lekach before returning the Torah to the ark?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Cf my answer here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69578/4940

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *Birkat HaShachar* we say וְהַעֲרֶב נָא יְיָ אֱלֹהֵינוּ
אֶת דִּבְרֵי תוֹרָתְךָ בְּפִינוּ -- make the words of Your torah **sweet** to us.  And lo!  When we reach this part of the torah service, where we have taken it out, read from it, savored it, and begun to return it, we can now declare that the torah Hashem gave us *is* in fact sweet.  The Holy One blessed be He hears prayer and answers, just like we said in *shomea t'filah*!  Before we have even completed the morning service we have proof positive of the efficacy of prayer!

The least we can do, therefore, is to serve *lekach* at the *kiddush*, as a reflection and reminder of the answer to our prayers.

Answer (score 4):

I think you misunderstand the verse. In many Shuls after Davening is over they give Lekach. The people in the Shul are saying that there is good Lekach for after Davening. The reason it is said at that point is due to people having tasted it just prior to Kriyas Hatorah at the Kidush club.

Comment: Gershon, either you or your shul is "old fashioned". I haven't seen lekach at a shul Shabbat kiddush in about 25 years. It seems that the only "formal setting" where I will find lekach is at a *chosson's tisch*. These days, I see 7-layer cake instead, among other cookies. It ain't the same :-(

Comment: Proud to be old fashioned.